# Android Studio resource file missing

Tags: android, android-listview, android-studio, android-resources, android-2.2-froyo

I want to create a `listview` with a simple list item in android studio, and as we all know we write `android.R.simple_list_item_1`.

However,  my problem is that when I type `android.` , I don't get in the suggestions the "R", I tried typing completing it manually and typing `android.R.` , but I don't get suggestions for list items and I get an error.

I checked my android sdk and java sdk paths and they're correct.

Why is the android resource file missing from the suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your class imports `YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME.android.R`

Second you need a first build inorder to have android.R file. Check if you have this file and if you haven't build your project. I believe building is called Sync Gradle in android studio.